# Visual Studio - C# 'out' variable intellisense completion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

In C#, I often use the "Try..." methods to retrieve a value via an `out` variable. For example, the `TryGetValue` method on `Dictionary`. I notice that Visual Studio 2019 IntelliSense shows a reasonable out parameter type and default variable name, like `out SubscriptionItem value` in the example shown below. However, I can't figure out a way to autocomplete this and accept the suggested parameter definition in the manner of an expanded snippet.

Is there a way to autocomplete this without manually typing out what IntelliSense is already suggesting?

[image]

Comment: One option is to type in `var value`. Not as fast as autocomplete, but quite fast to type.

Comment: `and accept the suggested parameter definition` The pedant in me compels me to highlight that that _isn't_ a suggested parameter definition. It is the definition of the `TryGetValue` function (the method you are calling).

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use var and accept the suggested name, then quick refactor to explicit type. Even so, I'm interested to know if true autocomplete is possible here...

Comment: You don't need to refactor. The `var` keyword is as explicit as `SubscriptionItem` is in this context.  When you use `var`, you are always creating a strongly typed variable.  The only type that is acceptable in that call is a `SubscriptionItem`, so when you say `out var value` it's exactly the same as `out SubscriptionItem value`.  If auto complete is possible, you should be able to type "S" followed by a `<tab>` and get the type type auto-completed.  If it doesn't work, well...

Comment: I just tried it.  You don't get magic auto-completion, but it's close.  If you type `out<space>` nothing pops up.  But, if at that point you press the *"hey autocomplete this for me"* sequence `<ctrl>+<space>` you get a useless auto-completion list.  But, if you then type the first character, it makes a pretty good guess at what you want.  Similarly if you type `out<space>S<tab>` you get a pretty good guess auto-completion list.  Since `out var` came into the language, I've pretty much only used it for this kind of parameter - it's much easier to remember and to type.

Comment: _"to use var....then quick refactor to explicit type"_ - don't mistake `var` as being some form of .NET equivalent to Visual Basic's `variant` type.  The former is _type-safe_ and _fast_ whilst the latter **isn't** on **both** points

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I agree that 'var' is an option and doesn't compromise on typing. Perhaps a preference on my part, but my current project is accumulating enough types to lose track. For me, less cognitive load to see what types are at a glance rather than having var everywhere. (My example shows the declaration close to the use, but that isn't always the case)

Comment: I've added this as a feature suggestion, just in case: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1108309/c-out-variable-intellisense-completion.html

Comment: @NoahStahl, since what you want cannot be obtained in intellisense so far and it is your own request, I suggest you could add an answer rather than a comment, and share the idea in the answer to help other community members understand this issue. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't appear Visual Studio does this yet, I've added a feature request to vote or track:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1108309/c-out-variable-intellisense-completion.html

Update: this is now an issue in the Roslyn GitHub repo:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/46268